# Rails + Nginx + Unicorn - unicorn.sock file is not created when deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm getting a "We're sorry, but something went wrong" screen upon attempting to deploy. It was previously working fine, however when I tried to update it, I ran into this issue. This is my first time deploying anything, and I'm still not exactly sure what I'm doing so I would really appreciate some input as to what I'm doing incorrectly.

I get the following error from **unicorn.log**

```
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.470419 #4905]  INFO -- : unlinking existing
socket=/home/deploy/production/appName/tmp/sockets
/bcrypt_unicorn.todo.sock
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.470635 #4905]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/home/deploy/production/appName/tmp/sockets/bcrypt_unicorn.todo.sock fd=10
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.470737 #4905]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.471045 #4905]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.471397 #4905]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.476589 #4908]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=4908
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.476714 #4908]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.477787 #4910]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=4910
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:53.477910 #4910]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:59.740522 #4908]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2018-10-01T19:54:59.744825 #4910]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
```

and the following error from **/var/log/nginx/error.log**:

```
2018/10/01 20:00:41 [crit] 5067#5067: *2 connect() to unix:/home/deploy
/production/appName/tmp/sockets/bcrypto_unicorn.todo.sock failed
(2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client:
77.75.77.32, server: , request: "GET /genres/gaming HTTP/1.1", upstream:
"http://unix:/home/deploy/production/appName/tmp/sockets
/bcrypto_unicorn.todo.sock:/genres/gaming", host: "appName.com"
```

I restarted Nginx with

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Reload the updated configuration

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Then stopped the running Unicorn process

```
ps aux | grep "unicorn master"
kill -9 PID
```

Then pulled updated code to deploy

```
git status
git stash save -u quick-fix
git pull origin master
git stash apply
```

Then migrated the db

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Then finally restarted Unicorn

```
bundle exec unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

My **unicorn.rb** file is as follows:

```
app_path = "/home/deploy/production/appName"
working_directory app_path
pid app_path + "/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path app_path + "/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path app_path + "/log/production.log"
listen app_path + '/tmp/sockets/bcrypt_unicorn.todo.sock'
worker_processes 2
timeout 65
```

**appName/config/nginx.conf**

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/sockets/bcrypto_unicorn.todo.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server{
  listen 80 default deferred;
  root /home/deploy/production/appName/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn{
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 403 404 /404.html;

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

and **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json    application/javascript text/xml applicati$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/bcrypto**

```
upstream bcrypto_unicorn {
    server unix:/home/deploy/production/appName/tmp/sockets/bcrypto_unicorn.todo.sock fa$
}

server {
    listen 80 default deferred;
    root /home/deploy/production/appName/public;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @bcrypto_unicorn;

    location @bcrypto_unicorn {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://bcrypto_unicorn;
    }

    error_page 422 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
}
```

Can someone please point me in the direction of what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Could you paste the error from `/log/unicorn.log`?

Comment: Original post has been updated with all new information

Comment: @mxvx To mark a question as resolved, you need to select a correct answer. There is no need for the huge text in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Nginx is looking for the socket in a different place that Unicorn has set it.

Nginx is trying to find the socket at: 
`/home/deploy/production/appName/tmp/sockets/byc2-master_unicorn.todo.sock` while the Unicorn config is setting it to `/tmp/appName_unicorn.todo.sock`

To solve the problem both paths must be the same. So you need to place the same path in the *upstream* directive of **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/bcrypto** and the one defined by the *listen* directive in **unicorn.rb**

Then restart Unicorn and reload Nginx

Comment: I still get the error:      F, [2018-10-01T16:27:31.522740 #1896] FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=/tmp/sockets/byc2-master_unicorn.todo.sock
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:137:in `initialize': No such file or directory - connect(2) for /tmp/sockets/byc2-master_unicorn.todo.sock (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: I updated my original post. Unicorn.log says **byc2-master_unicorn.todo.sock** is missing and /nginx/error.log says **bcrypt_unicorn.todo.sock** is missing. How would I fix this?

Comment: @mxvx, please update the question with the changes made, so its clearer to follow up. Also it would be very helpful if you add the Nginx config for your site, specially the part where you define the socket

Comment: @mxvx you still need to update the **unicorn.rb** config file. Nginx upstream must match the path of the unicorn socket. Then restart unicorn and reload Nginx

Comment: @mxvx, unicorn.log says it is listening in **bcrypt_unicorn.todo.sock** but nginx is searching for **bcrypto_unicorn.todo.sock**. There is a typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181108/discussion-between-r-sierra-and-mxvx).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, check your `tmp/sockets` folder to see whether its exists or not. If not, create the folder with following command

```
mkdir /home/deploy/production/appName/tmp/sockets
```

Then, change your `socket` to the same path with nginx by modify your `unicorn.rb`

```
listen app_path + '/tmp/sockets/bcrypt_unicorn.todo.sock'
```

Lastly, restart unicorn

```
bundle exec unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```